# One way bike rental Amsterdam to Paris

Tags: paris, amsterdam, rental

Is there a company that rents bicycles in Amsterdam (or anywhere in The Netherlands) for a one way trip to Paris?  In other words, pick up the bike in Amsterdam, and drop off in Paris 2 weeks later.

Comment: The answer is likely no but to help with giving you suggestions can you qualify what kind of bike or cycling journey to are thinking of?

Comment: One-way bike rentals are rare in Europe (and elsewhere), for many reasons. I'd suggest buying a bike in Amsterdam and selling it in Paris.

Comment: To be honest, I think you can forget about finding a one-way rental. Alternatively, you could rent a bike in Amsterdam and take a train back to return it. But even then, in my experience it's pretty much impossible to find bike rental that are not either city bikes or, in mountainous areas, (steeply priced) mountain bikes for day rentals. 
Realistically, your best and cheapest option would be to fly to Amsterdam (assuming youi're coming from CA) with your own bike as special luggage and use that.

Comment: I have seen one-way bicycle rentals in France and Italy. The company ListNRide offers one way rentals on several international routes. There are by now quite a few companies catering for and arranging support for long distance bicycle tours and I would not at all categorically rule out that there is a company offering this for Amsterdam-Paris as well.